# Deleting intervals from $(0,1):$ what is the resulting set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Take the open interval $(0,1)$.

- Split into *thirds* and consider only the open intervals at each end. We are left with:

  $$\big(0,\tfrac13\big)\cup \big(\tfrac23,1\big)$$ For each of these:
- Split into *quarters* and consider only the open intervals at each end. We are left with: $$\big(0,\tfrac{1}{12}\big)\cup \big(\tfrac{1}{4},\tfrac{1}{3}\big)\cup \big(\tfrac23,\tfrac34\big)\cup \big(\tfrac{11}{12},1\big)$$

  For each of these:
- Split into *fifths* $...$

$$\text{etc}.$$

Continuing this process indefinitely (a countably infinite amount of times), what are we left with?

Initially I would have said nothing, but having read and asked about similar Cantor set like things, I am not so sure...

Comment: @DanielFischer Read his question more carefully. It's not the Cantor set.

Comment: @DanielFischer  I don't think it can be described only using the ternary expansion, as at the second stage each remaining interval is quartered, at the third stage each remaining is cut in fifths, and so on.

Comment: @coffeemath Right, didn't see it was not the (closed) middle thirds that were removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get nothing -- every infinite sequence of "left" and "right" that doesn't eventually end in all "left"s or all "right"s will map to a sequence of nested open intervals where both right and left endpoints move towards each other. They therefore have a point in common that never gets removed.

In fact, if you use *closed* intervals instead of open ones, you get something that is homeomorphic to the usual middle-thirds Cantor set, so with open intervals the result is homeomorphic to the middle-thirds Cantor set without *its* interval endpoints.

It can be viewed as a "thin" analogue of a [fat Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set); how large a fraction of each interval you're removing at each step doesn't change the *topology* of the limit set (though it can change its *measure*, as the fat Cantor set shows).